# photoshop CC how to transform RGB and Alpha channels simultaneously

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

I'm trying to transform my whole image which contains an Alpha channel. When I `select all` with the Alpha channel visible, the transform does not apply to the Alpha channel. What can I do to transform the RGB and Alpha channels simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is flattened you can just:

- *Select All*.
- Click the RGB channel in the *Channels* panel.
- Shift-click the alpha channel in the *Channels* panel.
- Perform the wanted transformation.

Otherwise you can:

- Select the layer you want to transform.
- *Select All*.
- Perform the wanted transformation.
- *Select All*.
- Click the alpha channel in the *Channels* panel.
- Use *Edit > Transform > Again* to repeat the transformation.

Comment: 1st option: I tired this, but it wont highlight the channel and RGB. It will only select one or the other. 2nd option works !

Comment: Good to hear! The first option probably fails because your document has multiple layers? It only works with flat images.

Comment: no it was only 1 layer

Comment: But was it *flattened* (the only layer is called "Background" and has a lock symbol)?

Comment: I tried with it that way and the mouse had a cancel symbol or not permitted symbol. I then cloned the background layer and then removed the background. After that it still would not let me select both RGB and Alpha channel.

Comment: can you tell me why when I paste a selection that I copied that it doesnt paste in the same place as I copied it? It seems to be offsetting.

Comment: That should really be a whole new question. But OK, as a welcome gift . When you paste it's placed in the middle of the current selection (but always inside the canvas). If you have no selection it's placed in the middle of the current view. So to place in the exact same spot just keep the selection while pasting.